# I want to set a private field to test a function

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a bean that has the function getUser, this returns the currently logged in user, or finds one if the variable user is empty.

Do I have bad design in my bean, or should I just create a setUser function? I am not sure what the correct way to go is.

This is my test for that AuthorizationBean:

```
public class AuthorizationBeanTest {

    private AuthorizationBean authorizationBean;

    @Mock
    User user;

    @Mock
    UserDao userDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        authorizationBean = new AuthorizationBean();
        //I want to set the user to the mocked user so I can test the logout function
    }

    @Test
    public void doLogoutTest() {
        assertNotNull(authorizationBean.getUser());
        assertEquals("/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true", authorizationBean.doLogout());
        assertNull(authorizationBean.getUser());
    }

}
```

Here is the code from the bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "authBean")
@SessionScoped
public class AuthorizationBean implements Serializable{

    //Data access object for the users
    @Inject
    UserDao userDao;

    private User user; // The JPA entity.
    public User getUser() {
        if (user == null) {
            user = (User) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("user");
            if (user == null) {
                Principal principal = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
                if (principal != null) {
                    user = userDao.findByEmail(principal.getName()); // Find User by j_username.
                }
            }
        }
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Function that handles the logout
     * @return Redirect string that points to the login page
     */
    public String doLogout() {
        // invalidate the session, so that the session is removed
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        user = null;
        // return redirect to login page
        return "/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }


}
```

Comment: If the current code is working, I think its better that you post the question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Rather than to tweak your bean code for a test purpose wouldn't it possible to adapt the context your test is running in ? By forcing a user that would be retrieved by FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap() or FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal() ?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I think this question is actually better off on Stackoverflow. It's laser-focused on the question "Should I create a setter or keep my current code?". That's a very clean, clear and focused question and better off here. [codereview.se] answers aren't mandated to address the concerns of OP and as such posting to Code Review may not "yield" the best results

Comment: You should Mockito's `spy` mechanism.

Comment: @Vogel612, try to edit the question so it can be improved, "Do I have bad design in my bean?, ecc", it needs a clear problem statement, with desired result... (otherwise code review,  opinion based ecc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the user in the @Before method as following:

```
Mockito.when(authorizationBean.getUser()).thenReturn(user);
```

For doing so, you also need to mock the AuthorizationBean class though.

You can also omit the MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); invokation running the whole test with the Mockito runner, placing this annotation on the test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

**Update**: However, you would not be able to test AuthorizationBean mocking it indeed. There are several static method invocations in your bean, you could mock them with PowerMock, however usage of PowerMock is as well a bad smell for reviewing design.

**Update 2**: 
Using PowerMock you could actually do something like:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(FacesContext.class);
PowerMockito.when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(context);
```

Where context is yet another mock which would then populate the session map with your mocked user.

**Update 3**: don't forget to run your test case then using @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class). You can check an example [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/powermock-mockito-integration-example/) which goes more in details, but in case the link would be broken in the future, the instruction above should already give you a good start.

Comment: Isn't it bad to mock AuthorizationBean , because I am testing AuthorizationBean?

Comment: You are right, I also realized after posting the answer, I update it

Comment: The static methods are from JSF, I am not sure how I would do this differently. Also when running the test without checking first if user is not null, I get an error at the "getCurrentInstance" method invocation. Because in the unit test there is ofcourse no FacesContext.

Comment: Check the Update 2 to my answer on how to user PowerMock in this case.

Comment: I now have the my test like this: http://pastebin.com/GknB6hy2 . It works did I use PowerMock right?

Comment: Looks good. However, I would not mock the session map, it can be a normal Java object, new HashMap on which you invoke a put("user", user);

Answer (score 1):

What I generally do, to keep things simple, is I make the field package private and annotate it with [guava's `@VisibleForTesting`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html)

```
@VisibleForTesting User user; // The JPA entity.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the good (or bad, as you like) old `java.reflection` package to set a private field.

```
Field userField = authorizationBean.getClass().getDeclaredField("user");
userField.setAccessible(true);
userField.set(authorizationBean, someUser);
```

In the scope of a test, it is in my opinion not as bad as it looks...

Comment: Although in this case a field named user would rarely be renamed, what if that happen? That would break the test. And what if the same approach (using reflection in tests) would be applied over and over? The whole application/project may become harder to refactor.